# CSS library or theme which does not need html classes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I know there are several great css libraries, such as Bootstrap, Foundation.

But all of them follow the basic style that -- "You need to add html classes to tags in order to apply it".

Although it is convenient enough, I am just TOO lazy that I do not want to write some classes like `.form-control` of Bootstrap, since I just want all the input controls in my website follow the Bootstrap style by default.

I like the idea of CoC (Convention over configuration), so I imaged that there is a css library, which just replace the default looking by the browser. To use it, we do not need any changes on the HTML. This is Convention. In case of some special looking elements, we add classes on it.(Configuration)

That seems great, but I can not find any candidates by Google. So I make this a question to see if there are some good ideas.

So the question is:

1. Are there any existing libraries which follow my request?
2. If not, does this idea has some disadvantages so nobody do like this?

Comment: I cannot follow your request, how do you want to style a site without the use of classes? Do you only want to use HTML tags such as `h3`, `p`, ... etc?

Comment: Yes, I mean the CSS library customize HTML tags. For example, only by using `table` with no classes on it, we can get a good looking table on the page which is different from the default one rendered by the browser.

Comment: I do not quite understand why this question got down vote.

Comment: I guess it's because your question is not very clear. Only through the comment was I able to understand that you wanted a library that styles basic HTML tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check out http://getwirefy.com/, they offer what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to style basic elements (e.g. `table`, `p`, `a`) the way to do it is to have no prefix in your CSS.

For example:

```
p {color:#ccc;}
```

will render all of your paragraph elements grey. You can apply this to any html element.

The downside of this is that it doesn't allow for any specificity. In the above example, ***all*** of your paragraphs will be grey, whether you want them to be or not. If you wanted some of your paragraphs to have a different style, you'll either have to add a class (good) or use inline CSS styles (bad).

There are some workarounds, of course. You can nest CSS styles, so if you have the CSS:

```
p span {color:#00ff00;}
```

and the HTML

```
<p><span>Your blue text</span></p>
```

Then that text will appear in a different colour, but at that point you're making more work for yourself than just using a class, and potentially writing non-semantic HTML.